# How to make CSS in an external stylesheet inline (for email)?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, html-email

I have been using bits of the Foundation for Email HTML and CSS.

The CSS is in an external stylesheet. It is linked to in the HTML file. I've just used the Foundation inliner tool, expecting it to inline the (external) CSS, but it doesn't. I've also tried the MailChimp inliner tool.

Do I have to manually copy and paste the CSS into the HTML `<head> <style type="text/css">` before using an inliner tool?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I've just gone back to Foundation for Email inline tool and much to my surprise it is now allowing me to copy in my CSS stylesheet. Solved.